# Help understanding set

Tags: calculus, logic, proof-explanation

I am given the following, along with the following description:

> Assume all functions have domain $ \mathbb R $. I will define a new concept. For every pair of functions $ f $ and $ g $, we define the set
> $$ \Omega ^ g _ f = \{x \in \mathbb R : f ( x ) < g ( x ) \} \text . $$

**My Qestion:**
What exactly does this mean? I am being thrown off by the omega part. Why is $ g $ above $ f $? What exactly is this telling me and why is there the omega symbol? Is it just a random/convention variable name?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a **relation** between $f$ and $g$

Comment: Think about, from an **intuitive** viewpoint, what **has** to be intended here.  Let $D$ denote the subset of $R$ where $f(x) < g(x)$.  Then, whatever the *formal definitions* of the symbols, the **intent must be** to identify set $D$.

Comment: It seems to just be notation. If you like, you can think of it as $\Omega(f, g) = \{x \in \Bbb R : f(x) < g(x)\}$ instead.

Comment: @user2661923 so by fliping g and f does that mean the set changes from fx<gx to gx<fx?

Comment: Any answer that I give you would be speculative, since I am not familiar with the notation.  I was simply showing you how you can use your intuition to attack deciphering symbols that might otherwise seem like hieroglyphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this.

They are inventing a piece of notation, right then and there, and giving you the definition. That means you don't have to think about what each part means, at all. Just remember that from now on, each time you see an $\Omega$ with two functions attached to it, that's shorthand for a certain subset of the real numbers related to those two functions. Which subset? That's given by the right-hand side of the definition.

$\Omega_f^g$ is the subset of the real line given by where $g$ is larger than $f$. That's it.

> Why is $g$ above $f$

Presumably to remind you of the fact that we're interested in the region where the graph of $g$ is above the graph of $f$. A mnemonic, and nothing of actual mathematical consequence. The two function names must appear somewhere, and that's as good a place as any.

> why is there the omega symbol?

Presumably because the author thought it fitting for some reason. You need *something*, as just "$^g_f$" looks a bit strange. $\Omega$ is as good as any other symbol.

> Is it just a random/convention variable name?

Yes, that is exactly what it is. Presumably, these kinds of sets, given by where one function is larger than another, is going to appear a lot in the following text. They wanted a shorter way to write it, so they made up some new notation on the spot for that purpose. They are kind enough to inform you of this new notation through this definition, so that you too can more compactly enjoy the theorems and proofs that follow.

Comment: So what would occur if: flipping g and f. Does that mean the set changes from fx<gx to gx<fx? In a problem which proceeds this They are fliped

Comment: @isa123 If the definition stays the same, then the set is where the top function is larger than the bottom function. No matter what names they have. The definition uses $f$ and $g$ because they have to use _something_. Maybe a less confusing way to write the definition could be $$\Omega^{\square_2}_{\square_1}=\{x\in\Bbb R:\square_1(x)<\square_2(x)\}$$where the squares indicate empty places ready to be filled with two functions (and the numbers on the squares are there to tell you which square in the left corresponds to which square on the right). It has its own problems, but it may help you.